# Schedule login to Windows Server 2008 R2 Virtual Box

Tags: testcomplete

I have a test script created using TestComplete 10.0. The test script to uninstall then install a software and update config file. It hosted in a Windows 2008 R2 Virtual Box and I have tested using TestExecute and it runs successfully.

I have scheduled the run via Task Scheduler and I have created a bat file to run it. Task starts successfully but fails. I have searched in Google and found TestComplete fails when remote desktop session is disconnected for the user set to execute the task.

I have tried adding the **tscon  /dest:console** but did not successfull.

Is there any other way to login to Windows Server 2008 R2 Virtual Box?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is documented and the TestComplete Help file contains a number of possible solutions for it. You can find this information in the [Running Tests on Locked Computers](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/56550/) help topic of the tool.